# Specific day- sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I find a specific day no matter the year or date in sql oracle.
as an example
i have the folowing dates in and table
id         date
1          2013-02-03
2          2013-01-04
3          2012-06-13

I want to find all the ids with the day= 13

I've did this already but it doesn't work

```
select id
from table
where dayofmonth(date) = 13
```

this works in mysql but not in oracle.
Can any of you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use to_char() + to_num()

```
select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'DD')) from dual
```

or use the extract() function:

```
select extract (day from sysdate) from dual
```

**EDIT:**

To get all rows from a table whose day is 13, just use EXTRACT in the WHERE clause:

```
create table my_data as
(select 1 pk, to_date('2013-01-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as my_date from dual union all
 select 1 pk, to_date('2013-01-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as my_date from dual union all
 select 1 pk, to_date('2013-02-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as my_date from dual);

select * from my_data
where extract(day from my_date) = 13;
```

Comment: how should i use this more precisely?..it gives me all the results that i have written in the table:SELECT id_t 
FROM Test 
where  '13' = all(select extract (day from data) from test);